python: how to import a module that references another file in the same directory?
Here's my folder structure
/
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mod1.py
│   └── mod2.py

the contents of mod1.py:
class MyClass(object):
  pass

and mod2.py:
from mod1 import MyClass

This is a simple test of how modules work in python and I'm trying to figure out how to set up my environment so that mod2 can properly reference mod1.  When I'm inside package/, I can import either module without issue.
[package/] $ python
>>> import mod1
>>> import mod2
>>>

However, when inside /, I cannot import mod2:
[/] $ python
>>> from package import mod1
>>> from package import mod2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/package/mod2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mod1 import MyClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'
>>>

I believe the issue is that python is not set up for a module to consider its own directory as part of its PYTHONPATH, so it can't find mod1.  I tried adding . to the PYTHONPATH env var but that did not solve the issue.
Please note that this is a simplified example.  The code I am trying to work with is 3rd party code and my goal is to not have to keep all python files in the root directory of my repo.  Ideally I'm looking for a way to configure python such that any file can reference sibling files without the need to edit the code.

yes. That was a typo on my part. You'll notice from the error message that I was in fact importing mod1 in my file

I believe the issue is that python is not set up for a module to consider its own directory as part of its PYTHONPATH  <-- this is correct.  That worked in Python 2 but is no longer allowed in Python 3.  It only "works" when your cwd is in the package because of the first entry of sys.path being the empty string, and that is not something that can be relied upon.
